# Docker: running several contaners accessible from the Web

Tags: apache-2.2, docker

I have question to Docker. Now I run Apachce with different sites in different folders with configured virtualhosts. Now I want to run several Docker containers by name-based routing. How to do it? I had an idea with running each container on its own port, and use Apache to forward 80 or 443 to container's port. But I think, that it will be a big performance problem and I don't know how to configure it. Thanks.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve by using containers?

Comment: @Mircea Mostly deployment, because if I build container once, I can put it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have apache run for each virtual host the memory consumption and CPU usage would be higher, especially on a buddy site.

Docker would help you marginally with your deployment problems.

It would be useful if you intend to have different setups for each virtual host, like one with PHP, one with tomcat/Java.

If you want to have each host in a container, then you will need too allocate an IP addresses for each of them. You can have the hostnames in DNS, pointing to each respective IP.

No need to do port forwarding or reverse proxy. Think like having a VM for each apache instance. Each apache will be the container. Nothing else will run in it, unless you explicitly configure the container to run something else.

Of you want to use one single external IP, you can use a reverse proxy that be in the front of the containers.

Comment: My current configuration is not very clear, and I would like to have separated services. I think that building a container for an service is more efficient for development, and services are more separared.